# Moment generation function for continuous random variable

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Apologies, my math skills have become rusty and I'm having trouble with this question:

$X$ is a continuous random variable with 
$$f(x)=\cases{e^{-(x+2)}&\text{if } -2 < x < \infty\\0&\text{otherwise}}.$$

Find the MGF of $X$.

So far I have started with this below, but I'm unsure of how to find the derivative from here. I've only seen problems where $x$ is between $0$ and $\infty$ before so I'm not sure how to deal with $-2$.

$$M_X(t)=\int_{-2}^{\infty}e^{tx}e^{−(x+2)} dx$$

Thanks very much.

Comment: You need to find an anti-derivative to $e^{tx}e^{-(x+2)}$, not the derivative.

Comment: What I mean is, this is what I've done so far but it looks messy:

Comment: ∞−2e-(1-t)xe2dx

Comment: Then 1/(1-t) e-(1-t)xe2 and since its between infinity and -2 then my answer is Mxt = e-2t/(1-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $$e^{tx}e^{-(x+2)} = e^{(t-1)x-2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{e^{(t-1)x-2}}{t-1}\right)$$
Now integrate both sides with respect to $x$ over $[2,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried to Upvote you but it says I don't have a high enough reputation yet.

Comment: Not a problem. Just keep asking questions and accepting answers, and you will develop enough of a reputation quickly enough. You can even answer or comment on other questions too, all input is welcome  :)